# Hyperledger Composer Query Language CONTAINS operator

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

Can anyone here have an example of CONTAINS operator that uses parameter instead of static value in Hyperledger Composer Query Language? Can’t seem to work this kind of query:

WHERE (role CONTAINS _$role)

Maybe I’m doing it the wrong way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`CONTAINS` is used against an array field please note.

If role is a simple string (in your model), you do not need/use 'CONTAINS'. But I'll give you an example of `role` as a plain string or a role in an array of roles.

if role was defined as:

`o String role`

and rolesArray was:

`o String[] rolesArray`

here is an example of queries for either type:

```
query roleMatch {
  description: "String search"
  statement:
 SELECT org.acme.mynetwork.Trader WHERE (role == _$roleId)
}
```

Array search using CONTAINS:

```
query roleMatchinArray {
  description: "String search in Array"
  statement:
     SELECT org.acme.mynetwork.Trader 
     WHERE (rolesArray CONTAINS == _$roleId)
}
```

Calling the query in your transaction logic would look something like:

```
return query('roleMatch', {role: 'Role1' } )
        .then(function (results) {
          for (var n = 0; n < results.length; n++) {
        // process results objects
         }
        }); // etc
```

Comment: Thanks for this Paul. But do you have an example of LIKE operator in hyperledger? I thought CONTAINS operator has the same behavior with LIKE operator in RDBMS.